# JavaMail: Using a custom SSLSocketFactory for SSL

Tags: jakarta-mail

is there a way in javamail to use a SSLSocketFactory that uses a custom socket implementation?

I noticed the following when using SSL (IMAPS in this case) and my own socketFactories:

1) When I provide a javax.net.SocketFactory:

- creates a socket with socketFactory.createSocket()
- passes above socket to SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket(aboveSocket,host,port,autoclose)

  ```
  socket = sf.createSocket(); //create socket with my SocketFactory
  socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), cto);
  ssf = (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
  socket = ssf.createSocket(socket, host, port, true); // wrap my socket with SSLSocketFactory
  ```

2) Provide a javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory:

- creates java.net.Socket
- passes above socket to the SSLSocketFactory

  ```
  socket = new java.net.Socket();
  socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), cto);
  socket = ssf.createSocket(socket, host, port, true); // use my SSLSocketFactory
  ```

**What is the problem?**

- For 1) I'm not able to provide my own TrustManager.
- For 2) I will get a UnknownHostException when connecting due to usage of java.net.Socket instead of my custom socket

**What I need**

When using my own SSLSocketFactory, the socket used should be retrieved from the factory (instead of using a java.net.Socket). Code should be something like this:

```
socket = ssf.createSocket(); //create socket with my SSLSocketFactory
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), cto);
socket = ssf.createSocket(socket, host, port, true); // use my SSLSocketFactory
```

Any ideas how/if this can be done?

Thanks in advance
Best regards,
Manuel

Comment: It might be easier to take a step back and ask what problem you're trying to solve by creating your own socket implementation class?  You can definitely provide your own socket factory, but you might want to use [MailSSLSocketFactory](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/util/MailSSLSocketFactory.html).

Comment: @BillShannon Thanks for your reply. We require authentication against a socks5 proxy server that we use. This is done in our socket implementation. According to the FAQ, proxy authentication is not supported: https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#proxy I'm aware that we can provide our own SSLSocketFactory but javamail will call the factory with a java.net.Socket and it will not allow us to create our own Socket, right?

Comment: You can also provide your own plain SocketFactory.  Although an easier solution might be to use the [connect](https://bitbucket.org/gotoh/connect/wiki/Home) program to handle connecting through your proxy server through an external program.

Comment: I though I already provided a plain SocketFactory and noticed that the handshake failed due to missing certificates in the truststore (point 1)). Where would I need to provide my truststore if I'm using a plain SocketFactory. Is this possible?

Comment: Try the suggestions [here](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#installcert).